# IErrorHandler gives page not found for Json response in rest

Tags: wcf, ierrorhandler

For any webprotocol exception the errorhandler should handle the exception and give only json response instead gives the page not found.

Here is the configuration for the service

```
    <system.serviceModel>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
      <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
          <add name="enhancedWebHttp" type="Licensing.Services.EnhancedWebHttpElement, Licensing.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
        </behaviorExtensions>
      </extensions>
      <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="webBinding">
          </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
            <enhancedWebHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
          </behavior>
          <behavior name="poxBehavior">
            <enhancedWebHttp/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="Licensing.Services.restserviceBehavior" >
            <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true. Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <services>
        <service name="Licensing.Services.restservice" behaviorConfiguration="Licensing.Services.restserviceBehavior">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost/LicensingAPIService/restservice.svc"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
          contract="Licensing.Services.IRestService" />
          <endpoint address="pox" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior"
          contract="Licensing.Services.IRestService"/>
        </service>
      </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Here is the Code for enhancedWebHttp

```
public sealed class EnhancedWebHttpElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    #region Type specific properties

    [ConfigurationProperty("defaultBodyStyle", DefaultValue = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    public WebMessageBodyStyle DefaultBodyStyle
    {
        get
        {
            return (WebMessageBodyStyle)this["defaultBodyStyle"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["defaultBodyStyle"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("defaultOutgoingRequestFormat", DefaultValue = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public WebMessageFormat DefaultOutgoingRequestFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return (WebMessageFormat)this["defaultOutgoingRequestFormat"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["defaultOutgoingRequestFormat"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("defaultOutgoingResponseFormat", DefaultValue = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public WebMessageFormat DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return (WebMessageFormat)this["defaultOutgoingResponseFormat"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["defaultOutgoingResponseFormat"] = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Base class overrides

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        LicensingBehavior result = new LicensingBehavior();

        result.DefaultBodyStyle = this.DefaultBodyStyle;
        result.DefaultOutgoingRequestFormat = this.DefaultOutgoingRequestFormat;
        result.DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = this.DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat;
        return result;
    }

    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(LicensingBehavior);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here is the code for Licensing Behavior

```
public class LicensingBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
{

    protected override void AddServerErrorHandlers(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        int errorHandlerCount = endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Count;
        base.AddServerErrorHandlers(endpoint, endpointDispatcher);
        IErrorHandler webHttpErrorHandler = endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers[errorHandlerCount];
        endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.RemoveAt(errorHandlerCount);
        RestErrorHandler newHandler = new RestErrorHandler(webHttpErrorHandler,DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat);
        endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(newHandler);
    }        

}
```

Here is the code for ErrorHandler.

```
public class RestErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    IErrorHandler _originalErrorHandler;
    WebMessageFormat _format;
    public RestErrorHandler(IErrorHandler originalErrorHandler,WebMessageFormat format)
    {
        this._originalErrorHandler = originalErrorHandler;
        this._format = format;
    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        return error is WebProtocolException;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        WebProtocolException licensingException = error as WebProtocolException;
        if (licensingException != null)
        {

            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, null, new ValidationErrorBodyWriter(licensingException));
            if (_format == WebMessageFormat.Json)
            {
                HttpResponseMessageProperty prop = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
                prop.StatusCode = licensingException.StatusCode;
                prop.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                fault.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, prop);
                fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json));
            }
            else if(_format == WebMessageFormat.Xml)
            {
                HttpResponseMessageProperty prop = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
                prop.StatusCode = licensingException.StatusCode;
                prop.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
                fault.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, prop);
                fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Xml));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this._originalErrorHandler.ProvideFault(error, version, ref fault);
        }
    }

    class ValidationErrorBodyWriter : BodyWriter
    {
        private WebProtocolException validationException;
        Encoding utf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

        public ValidationErrorBodyWriter(WebProtocolException validationException)
            : base(true)
        {
            this.validationException = validationException;
        }

        protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("root");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "object");

            writer.WriteStartElement("StatusCode");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "string");
            writer.WriteString(this.validationException.StatusCode.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("Description");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "string");
            writer.WriteString(this.validationException.StatusDescription);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an empty ASP.NET project, copied the exact code which you have into it (changed some namespaces, nothing which should affect the result), and it worked out just fine - in the "json" endpoint a WebProtocolException is returned in JSON format, while in the "pox" endpoint the same exception is returned in XML format. You can download the project (called SO_7498771.zip) from https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=99984bbbec66d789&sc=documents&uc=1&id=99984BBBEC66D789%21944#, and compare it with your implementation, to see if there is anything different.

Comment: I was trying to run the service from the browser alone by just typing in the URL and for json response, if there is an exception then it gives file not found. Is this the desired result? Though it works fine with the ajax call.

Comment: Check which URL you're sending on the browser alone vs the one in the AJAX call; the server doesn't know (or care) where the requests come from.

Comment: I modified the service like this                              public Person GetPerson()
{throw new WebProtocolException { StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict, StatusDescription = "Conflict" };}                                                            For Json call in browser gives file not found. But the Ajax call works fine. The URL is same in these cases is               http://localhost/SO_7498771/RestService.svc/json/GetPerson but the POX call works fine in both ajax and Browser and URL is http://localhost/SO_7498771/RestService.svc/pox/GetPerson

Comment: Check in a networking inspector (such as Fiddler, or the browser's F12 networking analyzer) what is the difference between the ajax request and the browser one. That difference should explain what problem you're having.

Comment: The request seems to be same in both browser and in Ajax. I checked the request and response in F12 and Fiddler. The json putput is returned correctly. I guess  the browser is not able to display the Json output returned from the server.

Comment: The browser really isn't able to display JSON returned from the server - and what it does with it depends on the browser (IE may prompt you to save it; I don't know what Chrome/FF does). But it shouldn't say that the file wasn't found. Then your issue is solved, right :)?